# How to remove the final character in an ASCII file

Tags: c#, vb.net, ascii

I'm creating an ASCII file and the users need the final CR/LF removed.

I've tried removing the final character but it is simply witten back once the file saves.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    sb.Append(row["Beneficial Owner Name"].ToString().Trim().PadRight(75));
    sb.Append(delimiter);

    yada yada...

    sb.Append("\r\n");
}
```

The text is returned to the VB calling function like this:

```
myfile = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(save.FileName, True)
myfile.WriteLine(textData)
myfile.Close()
```

I need an output that looks like this:

[image]

not like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: sb.Append("\r\n");  If you do not want the last row put the return before the append, except for row 1, so you do not get a blank row at the beginning.

Comment: WriteLine. LINE. It writes a newline after the text

Comment: You can try using `myfile.Write(textData)` instead of `myfile.WriteLine(textData)`

Comment: Thanks. myfile.Write(textData) (not WriteLine) is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let's mark this as answered.

```
myfile.Write(textData) (not WriteLine)
```

is the solution